# Polymer 1.0 App-Drawer - Uncaught TypeError when not rendered via dom-if

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-starter-kit

Displaying the menu only to members
I've got this bit of code

```
<app-drawer-layout fullbleed>

  <!-- Drawer content -->
  <template is="dom-if" if="{{signedIn}}">
   <app-drawer>
   ....
```

This displays the menu only when users are logged in to the application. It works fine but is there anyway to remove the error it causes in the console.

error:

```
polymer-mini.html:2046 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getWidth' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layout logic in `<app-drawer-layout>` [requires an `<app-drawer>` to determine the appropriate container margins](https://github.com/PolymerElements/app-layout/blob/85727a1/app-drawer-layout/app-drawer-layout.html#L218). I don't see an option to disable that logic.

A workaround for the error you're seeing is to create an empty `<app-drawer>` by moving the `dom-if` inside the `<app-drawer>`:

```
<app-drawer>
  <template is="dom-if" if="{{signedIn}}">
    ...
  </template>
</app-drawer>
```

This unfortunately would create a blank drawer before the user signs in, but maybe this is acceptable for your app. [codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/yJOKKM?editors=1001)