# Polymer app-drawer opening the page with it hidden

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-starter-kit

I've installed a new Polymer Starter Kit, and have the code below.

```
<app-drawer-layout fullbleed>

      <!-- Drawer content -->
        <app-drawer>
          <app-toolbar>
```

How can I make the app-drawer element be closed when the layout loads?

If i trigger .close() on the element when should I run this? 
It won't work for *ready* or *attatched* life cycle callbacks

But that would mean the menu opens and closes which i would like to avoid, what i really want to happen is when the page loads the menu is closed,

when I get a callback from the server to say the user is authenticated then call

```
this.$.menu.open() // where i've given app-drawer the if of menu
```

Answer (score 10):

If what you want is to not display the drawer no matter the viewport width unless the user interacts, all you need to do is to set the `app-drawer-layout`'s `forceNarrow` property to true like this:

```
<app-drawer-layout fullbleed force-narrow>
  <!-- Content -->
</app-drawer-layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is a follow up to: [Polymer 1.0 App-Drawer - Uncaught TypeError when not rendered via dom-if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37799018/polymer-1-0-app-drawer-uncaught-typeerror-when-not-rendered-via-dom-if/37801756#37801756)

Given:

```
<app-drawer-layout id="layout" fullbleed>
  <app-drawer id="drawer">
  ...
  </app-drawer>
</<app-drawer-layout>
```

You could set the `<app-drawer>.hidden` property and then [`<app-drawer-layout>.resetLayout()`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/app-layout#method-resetLayout) based on the new value of `signedIn`, using an observer:

```
Polymer({
  ...
  properties : {
    signedIn: {
      type: Boolean,
      value: false,
      observer: '_signedInChanged'
    }
  },
  _signedInChanged: function(signedIn) {
      this.$.drawer.hidden = !signedIn;
      this.$.layout.resetLayout();
  }
);
```

<sup>[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/yJOKog?editors=1001)</sup>